# Blocking Thread with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, rx-swift

Below is the simplified version of my project I'm struggling now.

I'd like to block the thread **until first `Single` succeeds.**
These observables should be **two separated streams but sharing one thread**.

Do you have any idea of fixing this code? Thanks!

```swift
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
var hasReturnedSingle = false

func returnSingle() -> Single<String> {
    return Single<String>.create { single in
      print("hasReturnedSingle: \(hasReturnedSingle)")

      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3.0) {
        single(.success(()))
        hasReturnedSingle = true
      }
      return Disposables.create()
    }
}

returnSingle().asObservable()
    .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .asSingle()
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

returnSingle().asObservable()
    .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .asSingle()
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**Result:**

```
hasReturnedSingle: false
hasReturnedSingle: false
```

**Expectation:**

```
hasReturnedSingle: false
hasReturnedSingle: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The `subscribeOn` operator affects the thread that the producer *starts* on, i.e the thread that the print statement runs on, but not the thread that DispatchQueue runs on. So the first call prints, pushes the block onto the main dispatch queue then completes. Then the second call does the same. Then the dispatches fire.

You can fix the problem any of a number of ways depending on how much control you have over the code in the producer function:

- write the producer function in a sequential format instead of dispatching.
- pass a scheduler into your `returnSingle` function and then use it instead of the DispatchQueue.
- run all the operations into a subject and then concatMap the subject's emissions.